# returning strings corresponding to shell glob matching

Tags: shell, filenames, wildcards

Suppose I have a subdirectory called `sub`. Then I want to operate on all files in that directory with the extension "txt". I want something like

```
for f in sub/*.txt
do
    enscript -b "" -o {$f basename excluding .txt}.ps sub/{$f basename excluding .txt}.txt                                                                                                                             
    ps2pdf {$f basename excluding .txt}.ps {$f basename excluding .txt}.pdf
done
```

So if there was just one file in the `sub` directory of the form `*.txt`, say `sub/foo.txt`, the script should expand to

```
enscript -b "" -o foo.ps sub/foo.txt                                                                                                                                   
ps2pdf foo.ps foo.pdf
```

I generally prefer portable solutions, but it is always interesting to learn about different ways of doing things. So non-portable is Ok, please just mention whether your solution is portable or non-portable. Also, the title is probably not the best possible, so feel free to modify.

EDIT: I realized the example as written did not quite make sense, since `foo.txt` was in the `sub` directory, and therefore `sub/foo.txt` would need to be passed to `enscript`. I also changed the -p `enscript` option to the more standard `-o` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIX shells (e.g., bash, dash, ksh, …) accept a `${var%suffix}` construct that
can be used to remove the trailing portion from the value of a
variable.  For instance, if `path="sub/file.txt"`, then `${path%.txt}`
expands to `sub/file`.

There's a symmetric construct to remove a prefix: `${var#prefix}`. The prefix can be a pattern. Doubling the `#` strips the longest matching prefix. For example, if `path=sub/dir/file.txt`, then `${path##*/}` expands to `file.txt` (and `${path#*/}` expands to `dir/file.txt`). The same goes for suffixes and `%`.

So, in your case you could write this (note that you can't combine the prefix stripping and the suffix stripping into a single expansion, at least not with only POSIX constructs):

```
for f in sub/*.txt; do
  base=${f%.txt}
  base=${base##*/}
  enscript -b "" -o "$base.ps" "$f"
  ps2pdf "$base.ps" "$base.pdf"
done
```

Alternatively, the GNU
[basename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) command accepts an
optional second argument which is the file extension to remove.  For
instance, if `$f` is `file.txt`, then `$(basename $f .txt)` expands to
`file`.

Note, however, that `basename` removes all path information except for
the last component, so if you want to remove just the extension you
have to put that back (see the
[dirname](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) command).

Comment: @Riccardo: Wow, that was fast. Thanks for replying. A comment and a question. 1) the link for `basename` has a typo (/ instead of .) and 2) these are links to what look like C utilities. Am I missing something? I should have said that my general preference for shell scripts is portability, so the `${path%.txt}` will do me. I'm guessing the GNU `basename` thing, whatever it is. is not portable.

Comment: @Riccardo: I think your script has an error. Run exactly as written I get the error: `syntax error near unexpected token `prefix=${f%.txt}'`. If I take out the semi-colon and add a `do` it works.

Comment: @Gilles: You forgot to fix the `basename` url. :-)

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: Fixed the links.  I guess the Gilles fixed the script already, as I can run it correctly?

Comment: @Riccardo: He did, yes. It just needed the addition of a `do`. Thanks.

Comment: @Riccardo: The script above doesn't quite work, as the directory name `sub/` is not stripped. Per [the Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) using `basename=${prefix#sub/}` will work.

Comment: A correction.  Bash is not a POSIX-comformant shell. Using the bash POSIX mode (set -o posix) gets you closer to POSIX conformance but does not make it fully conformant.

Comment: @Riccardo: I've made some corrections to my script in the question. Just mentioning it in case you feel like adjusting your answer.

Comment: @Gilles: thanks for editing to comply with the modified question!

Answer (score 4):

[The portable way is to strip the extension with `${f%.*}` and the directory with `${f##*/}` (or use `basename`)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14063/returning-strings-corresponding-to-shell-glob-matching/14064#14064).

In zsh, you can apply [various transformations](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to [parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion), including [history modifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) such as `r` to strip one extension and `t` to strip the directory part.

```
for x in sub/*.txt; do
    enscript -b "" -o ${x:t:r}.ps $x
    ps2pdf ${x:t:r}.ps ${x:t:r}.pdf
done
```

You can apply history modifiers to [glob patterns](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) as well.

```
for x in sub/*.txt(:r:t); do
    enscript -b "" -o $x.ps sub/$x.txt
    ps2pdf $x.ps $x.pdf
done
```

Comment: Like @Riccardo's version, this does not strip the leading `sub/`. As commented above, `basename=${prefix#sub/}` works, along the same lines as @Riccardo's approach.

Comment: well, `zsh` is clearly handy. Thanks.

Comment: I've made some corrections to my script in the question. Just mentioning it in case you feel like adjusting your answer.